# Can \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff be nested?

Tags: expl3, latex3

Consider the code

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
% ... lots of stuff 1 ...
\ExplSyntaxOn
% ... lots of stuff 2 ...
\ExplSyntaxOff
% ... lots of stuff 3 ...
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(a) How is stuff at positions 2 and 3 interpreted at the moment: as LaTeX2e code or as expl3 code?

(b) Is such code supposed to be interpreted at all, and, if so, how?

(An aside: such constructs started appearing in my files due to copy-and-paste.)

Comment: No. When you do `\ExplSyntaxOff`, the state is reverted to normal category codes. Just copy and paste the part *between* them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't. There's no stack implemented.

When `\ExplSyntaxOn` is encountered, some characters have their category code are changed, but their previous category code is stored in the definition of `\ExplSyntaxOff` (that does nothing, by default).

When `\ExplSyntaxOff` is next encountered, it resets the category codes to the previous states and redefines itself to do nothing.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_show:N \ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_show:N \ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOff
\tl_show:N \ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOff

\stop
```

And here's the output on the terminal: you see that the `expl3` codes are not valid any longer after the first `\ExplSyntaxOff` and `\tl_show:N` raises an error.

```
> \ExplSyntaxOff=\char_set_catcode:nn {9}{10}\char_set_catcode:nn
{32}{10}\char_set_catcode:nn {34}{12}\char_set_catcode:nn
{38}{4}\char_set_catcode:nn {58}{12}\char_set_catcode:nn
{94}{7}\char_set_catcode:nn {95}{8}\char_set_catcode:nn
{124}{12}\char_set_catcode:nn {126}{13}\tex_endlinechar:D =13\scan_stop:
\bool_set_false:N \l__kernel_expl_bool \cs_set_protected:Npn \ExplSyntaxOff
{}.
<recently read> }

l.5 \tl_show:N \ExplSyntaxOff

? 
> \ExplSyntaxOff=\char_set_catcode:nn {9}{10}\char_set_catcode:nn
{32}{10}\char_set_catcode:nn {34}{12}\char_set_catcode:nn
{38}{4}\char_set_catcode:nn {58}{12}\char_set_catcode:nn
{94}{7}\char_set_catcode:nn {95}{8}\char_set_catcode:nn
{124}{12}\char_set_catcode:nn {126}{13}\tex_endlinechar:D =13\scan_stop:
\bool_set_false:N \l__kernel_expl_bool \cs_set_protected:Npn \ExplSyntaxOff
{}.
<recently read> }

l.8 \tl_show:N \ExplSyntaxOff

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \tl
        _show:N \ExplSyntaxOff
?
```

Answer (score 5):

`\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are *switches* that change certain category codes to allow for a different coding syntax. They're synonymous to the [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pairs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) used to allow `@`'s in macros.

A showcase of something similar using font *switches* may be conclusive:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\bfseries
First % ... lots of stuff 1 ...
\bfseries
Second % ... lots of stuff 2 ...
\mdseries
Third % ... lots of stuff 3 ...
\mdseries
Last % ... lots of stuff last ...

\end{document}
```

One could consider `\mdseries` reverting what `\bfseries` has done, but that doesn't imply they are nestable.

Switches are not the same as grouping, which provides a scope as well as nesting.